# One line code examples in various languages for MD5

Tags: md5

I'm looking for one line code examples in various languages for getting a valid MD5 result (as a string, not a bytehash or what have you).  For instance:

PHP:
$token = md5($var1 . $var2);

I found VB especially troublesome to do in one line.

Comment: I think, this question would perfectly fit to [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). Maybe, it should be migrated there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C#:

```
string hash = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(input, "md5");
```

VB is virtually the same.

Here it is not using the System.Web namespace:

```
string hash = Convert.ToBase64String(new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)));
```

Or in readable form:

```
string hash =
     Convert.ToBase64String
     (new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
          .ComputeHash
              (System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes
                  (input)
              )
     );
```

Comment: Wow, that's an awful function name.

Comment: Agreed, I don't understand why they implemented SHA1,SHA2 and MD5, yet chose that method name, and decided against using a strongly typed enumeration for the hash method...Must have been written on a friday.

Comment: Microsoft's developers seem to like building deep hierarchies. I've seen this madness before in VBA... :-)

Comment: I would use the one with MD5CryptoServiceProvider (and the ancillary encoding classes).

Answer (score 2):

**Python**

```
token = __import__('md5').new(var1 + var2).hexdigest()
```

or, if `md5` is alrady imported:

```
token = md5.new(var1 + var2).hexdigest()
```

*Thanks to Greg Hewgill*

Comment: Easier: token = md5.new(var1+var2).hexdigest()

Answer (score 2):

There is a kind of universality in how this is to be accomplished. Typically, one defines a routine called `md5_in_one_line` (or `Md5InOneLine`) once, and uses it all over the place, just as one would use a library routine.

So for example, once one defines `Md5InOneLine` in C#, it's an easy one-liner to get the right results.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you really just asking "what languages have std. library support for MD5?"  As Justice said, in any language that supports it, it'll just be a function call storing the result in a string variable.  Even without built-in support, you could write that function in any language!

Comment: It's for a document's examples section.  Where possible I'd like to inform the audience "here's how you get the MD5 of a string", but didn't want to put in pages and pages of code examples.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you need VBScript:
download the [MD5 class](http://www.webdevbros.net/2007/12/29/using-gravatar-in-classic-asp/) from webdevbros and then with one line:

```
hash = (new MD5).hash("some value")
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it really matter if you can do MD5 in one line.  If it's that much trouble that you can't do it in VB in 1 line, then write your own function.  Then, when you need to do MD5 in VB in one line, just call that function.

If doing it all in 1 line of code is all that important, here is 1 line of VB. that doesn't use the System.Web Namespace.

```
Dim MD5 As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider() : Dim HashBytes() As Byte : Dim MD5Str As String = "" : HashBytes = MD5.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MyString")) : For i As Integer = 0 To HashBytes.Length - 1 : MD5Str &= HashBytes(i).ToString("x").PadLeft(2, "0") : Next
```

This will hash "MyString" and store the MD5 sum in MD5Str.

Comment: Why the loop? Use Convert.ToBase64String();

Comment: Because MD5 isn't usually represented in base 64.

Comment: Why not? A byte array can be represented however you want.

Comment: Didn't say you couldn't.  Just saying it's not usually represented that way.

Answer (score 0):

Coldfusion has a bunch of hashing algorithms, MD5 is the default.

cfset var md5hashresult = hash("string to hash")